# Headers and client library minor version mismatch for mysqli MariaDB

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this versions of headers:

```
PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u5

Client API header version   5.5.31
```

and I get this message : 
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50531 Library:100004
the reason is the version mismatch i think , How can I recompile PHP to match the version of mysqli ? 
I'm using mariadb

```
Client API library version  10.0.4-MariaDB
```

thanks !

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when i recently upgrade my ubuntu server to 13.04 anyway this is just a warning from `libmysqlclient` i also have mariadb , you can use `php5-mysqlnd` instead of `php5-mysql` this fixed it for me.

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-mysql

sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

Comment: -1 - decidedly worse: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mysqli' not found

Comment: @danorton Sounds like you need to install [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php).